# Linking failed in rust bindgen

Tags: rust, rust-bindgen

So I have a header library (a directory of .h files) that I need to make use of in my rust code. To get this working I have been looking into various crates to help me achieve the this and it seems like bindgen is the most promising option.
i followed the documentation for bindgen and have created a wrapper.h and a build.rs file.
in the build.rs file i have whitelisted all the needed functions, and the link parameter mentioned in the documentation specified as `println! ("cargo:rustc-link-lib=C/complete path to my header files");`.
when doing a cargo build this however fails with this error:

```
error: linking with link.exe failed: exit code: 1181
```

which I have not been able to find a solution for.
Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not link against a header file, but a library instead. Typically either `.lib`, `.dyn`, `.so` or `.a`.

Answer (score 0):

`rustc-link-lib` directive is only for `.a`/`.so`/`.dll` and cannot work with either `.h` or `.rs` files. It's completely inappropriate here.

If you make your `build.rs` script write to a directory specified by `std::env::var("OUT_DIR")` path, then your main library code can include it dynamically with:

```
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/temp_file_built_by_build_dot_rs.rs"));
```

Alternatively, don't bother with `build.rs` at all. Use command-line bindgen and include generated `.rs` file as a module in your project (just as a regular source code file).